# Affable Bean Java EJB Glassfish tutorial issues in netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I have been following the affableBean tutorial from the NetBeans site located [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/transaction.html).
I have run into an issue where I am unable to submit a purchase order(checkout.jsp). When I submit the form data, I receive an http 500 status and the following errors:

> WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OrderManager, method: public int session.OrderManager.placeOrder(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,cart.ShoppingCart)
>   WARNING:  EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OrderManager, method: public int session.OrderManager.placeOrder(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,cart.ShoppingCart)
>   WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
>       at session.**EJB31_Generated_*OrderManager*_Intf_***Bean*_.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
>       at controller.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:201)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>
> Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean
>   Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean
>   Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded
>   ConstraintViolations for details.     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:62)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:698)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:641)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:200)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4234)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:513)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:440)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:269)
>     at session.OrderManager.addOrder(OrderManager.java:88)  at
>   session.OrderManager.placeOrder(OrderManager.java:56)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)    at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
>     at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
>     ... 30 more

Line 201 of ControllerServlet is:
int orderId= orderManager.placeOrder(name,email,phone,address,cityRegion,ccNumber,cart);

Line 88 and 56 of OrderManager is:em.persist(customer);
                                  em.persist(order);

While running a debug session, it seems that persist method has null value in both case.my conclusion is that because there is no id genreated by database so it persist method has null value.
i do not understand what i do now to persist data in the my database table.
thanks for reply.

Comment: @BalusC - sir thanks for advice , i m sorry for that i didn't write it properly i edited my question , i hope u can now understand well   .i need help ,no one here for help me thanks for reply sir

Answer (score 1):

The customer_order table doesn't expect a null value of datecreated (though it provided a default timestamp). The CustomerOrder ejb also puts a @NotNull annotation on dateCreated. Yet line 201 does not pass the dateCreated value for CustomerOrder object constrnction.

So you either do one of the following
 - Disable the @NotNull annotation (though bad idea!)
 OR 
 - provide the dateCreated value in the default constructor of the CustomerOrder class.

```
public CustomerOrder() {
    // set dateCreated to timestamp ...
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    dateCreated = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
}
```

Edgar